# broken upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I was trying to upgrade from eoan ermine to focal fossa by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

It has run into some issues and its now showing :

[image]

Some other issues are with LibreOffice after running `sudo apt-get check`:

[image]

After running `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` :

[image]

Anyone has any idea how to fix these issues?

Comment: A Partial Upgrade is usually offered when you have non-Ubuntu sources that conflict with your normal Ubuntu sources. Best practice is to refuse the Partial Upgrade, uninstall all of your non-Ubuntu software, then try upgrading again. You can re-install your non-Ubuntu software after a successful upgrade.

Comment: maybe something to do with wine:   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but 4.0.2-1 is installed
 wine64 : Depends: libwine (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but 4.0.2-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Omnicacorp, is it Ubuntu 20.04 Server or Desktop?

Comment: its the Desktop version,idk is the server version better at stuff like ram and cpu management?